# Prolog: how to check if list contains list from numerous facts

Tags: list, prolog

I am new to prolog and trying to figure out how to solve this one.
Number1,number2, and number3 are cake names.
chocolate,mango,lemon... are ingredients and numbers after that are prices which I don't need to use for this query but they must be there.

```
icecream(number1,  [chocolate,mango,lemon], 1.99).

icecream(number2, [vanille,lemon ], 1.79).

icecream(number3, [almonds, kiwi, walnut], 2.50).
```

query:

```
which_icecream( [vanille,lemon,chocolate,mango],  S).

      S = number1;

      S = number2.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `member/2` twice for non-deterministic intersection:

```
which_icecream(DesiredIngredients, S) :-
    icecream(S, Ingredients, _),
    member(X, DesiredIngredients),
    member(X, Ingredients).
```

Note that will return same result multiple times, due to many ingredients matching multiple times:

```
?- which_icecream([vanille,lemon,chocolate,mango], S).
S = number1 ;
S = number1 ;
S = number1 ;
S = number2 ;
S = number2 ;
false.
```

Strip duplicates with `setof/3`:

```
?- setof(S, which_icecream([vanille,lemon,chocolate,mango], S), IceCreams).
IceCreams = [number1, number2].
```

---

An alternative solution, using `intersection/3` builtin:

```
which_icecream(DesiredIngredients, S) :-
    icecream(S, Ingredients, _),
    intersection(Ingredients, DesiredIngredients, Intersection),
    Intersection \= [].
```

Comment: Thank You kind sir for you fast answer!
When i compile this in prolog all i get in response is     number1. It doesn't write number2 at all.
How is that?
How is that?

Comment: After you get the `number1` answer, you must press the `;` (semicolon) or possibly the `Space` key to get the next answer. Did you do that? Pressing `Enter` will tell Prolog that you *don't* want any more answers.